# R - check whole vector in if clause

Tags: r, if-statement

here is a little example:

```
foo <- 1:5
foo < 6
> TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
if(foo < 6) {   # if(foo[1]<6 & foo[2]<6 & foo[3]<6 ...
  # do something
}
```

And I need a if-claus if 3 elements are true (order is not important), e.g.

```
bar <- c(1,3,6,8,2)
if(bar < 5) {   # if 3 values are true
   # do something
}
```

Thx for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for `all()`.

```
> all(foo < 6)
[1] TRUE
```

And for the second part, just do

```
if (sum(bar < 5) == 3) {}
```

This works because logical vector is coerce to numeric as 0 and 1.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Bang bang </blow smoke from barrel>. :) You're faster 99% of the time, though.